# JavaScript function to run at an interval on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, triggers

I am trying to run a function on Firebase at an interval automatically.  The references I found are either HTTP triggered or database triggered.

Please help and point me in the right direction.

thank you,

Jerry

Comment: Are you talking about Cloud Functions?

Comment: yes cloud functions, or if there is another way of doing it.  I have javascript function to run and pull rss feed and write them to firebase database.  I want to run this function daily to update feeds daily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Cloud Function that is triggered via HTTP requests, see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

To trigger the Cloud Function, you would call its URL (like `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/xxxx`).

You can use an online CRON job service like https://cron-job.org/en/ in order to call it regularly (daily in your case).